# Why would an App Engine datastore entity have different value when it shows up in a query than when it is accessed directly?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

I have a saved entity in app engine that shows a different value for the status field when it shows up in a query than when I access it directly. I've flushed the cache several times in the admin page and the values are still different. It has been like this for over an hour. What would cause this?

Note: I would post pictures but I don't have enough rep. On the query page, the entity's status is listed as "active" when I click through to that entity's individual page, it show's the value of "inactive".

Comment: Something is going on. Other users report the same problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?show_docid=fae072cf1c7db8b1#!topic/google-appengine/dRUabeuAoRo

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15010

Comment: Thanks, Glad I saw this. I was 99% sure it wasn't my code or any of my configurations but now I can be 100%